# Can't locate MIME/Types.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I wish to use Perl Module, without installing them, means without following below procedure,

perl Makefile.PL then make then & make test & make install

I have gz and rpm file of perl module, extracted files from gz and rpm file, But, Could not manage how to use these PM in my perl script, Structure is like as below

```
MyFunctionModule <Dirctory> 
    MyFunctionModule PerlModule 
        MyFunctionModule <Dirctory> 
            ConnectionPerlModule
            ResultPerlModule
            OutputPerlModule
            ErrorPerlModule
```

Please help....

Comment: Does [this](https://pastebin.com/JGaLhyBR) represent the structure you are trying to communicate?

Comment: Why don't you want to build them properly? Some Perl modules are written (partly or entirely) in C, so need compiling, etc. If you don't have permission to install them system-wide, you can use local::lib to set up a directory somewhere convenient to install Perl modules into.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a line like `use MIME::Types;` or `require MIME::Types;` in a Perl script, the Perl interpreter searches the module in a list of include directories. You can see the contents of that list (it is the variable `@INC`) by running the command `perl -V`:

```sh
...
  @INC:
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-2level
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0/darwin-2level
    /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0
```

This is just an example. Your mileage may vary. Say, one of the directories in the list is `/path/to/perl/libs`, then it would search the definition of the package `MIME::Types` in the file `/path/to/perl/libs/MIME/Types.pm`. In other words: Perl translates every `::` to a slash (`/`) and adds the Perl module file extension `.pm`. The error message you see means that Perl has tried to find a file `MIME/Types.pm` in every directory listed in `@INC` without success.

You can manipulate `@INC` before you `use MIME::Types;` so that Perl will find the file in the location you have installed it. The canonical way is to do it like this:

```perl
BEGIN {
    unshift @INC, '/path/to/perl/libs';
}
use MIME::Types;
```

The call to `unshift()` prepends the directory `/path/to/perl/libs` to `@INC`. Perl will then first look in `/path/to/perl/libs` before looking in any other directory that `perl -V` has listed under `@INC`. The above can be written more nicely like this:

```perl
use lib '/path/to/perl/libs';
use MIME::Types;
```

This is absolutely equivalent to the `BEGIN` block with `unshift` above. The effect is always that Perl will try to load the definition of the package `MIME::Types` from `/path/to/perl/libs/MIME/Types.pm`.

While it doesn't hurt to understand this mechanism, you are probably on the wrong track. You just want to use the module `MIME::Types`, but there is no need to install that module manually with the usual plethora `perl Makefile.PL && make && make install`. You have better options for that.

1. Your vendor will have a pre-compiled package for it. For example, if you are using Ubuntu Linux, you can probably install it with `sudo apt-get install MIME-Types`.
2. Try `cpanm MIME::Types` or `sudo cpanm MIME::Types` (if the first command fails with "access denied"). If you get something like "-bash: cpanm: command not found" try to find a package `cpanm`, `App-cpanminus` or the like for your platform.
3. If all of the above fail, just use the command `cpan` (or `sudo cpan`, when you get an "Access denied") which will open something like a command-line shell. Type there `install MIME::Types` and follow the instructions.

If you are not allowed to use `sudo` to install software with superuser privileges, you probably need [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/). It installs one or more private Perl interpreters in your home directory, so that you can install whatever other module you want without running into any permission problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that `use MIME'Types` is equivalent to `use MIME::Types` but I didn't want to confuse the author of the question with that ugly feature.

Answer (score 0):

If the Perl Module is really just a PM file (with no other compiled code or other dependencies), you can use it directly without installing it, you just need the `use lib` statement before you `use` the module.  Let's say you have the Types.pm file (from MIME::Types) in /opt/perl/modules, use this in your code:

```
use lib "/opt/perl/module";
use Types;
```

Comment: For a curiosity I'm asking. If the `.pm` doesn't have any dependency on any external modules, is it good way to put `Types.pm` file into `/opt/perl/module` directly?

Comment: That works more or less by accident but it is not a helpful answer. You would rather install the file as `/opt/perl/module/MIME/Types.pm` and then use it with `use MIME::Types`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Guido, put the PM into a folder called MIME, and use the full “use MIME::Type;”. That will make it more compatible if you move your script to another system that does have the module installed properly.